# Sending message to a group chat using bot framework from teams

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I want to proactively send a message to a group that the bot was added to (not a team, a simple group chat)

What I'm doing so far is saving (in memory) the conversation Id in a singleton dictionary
and then issue the notification to all conversations.
This is the API endpoint code..

```cs
        public CINotificationsController(
            IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter adapter,
            IBot bot,
            IConfiguration config,
            ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> conversationReferences,
            ILogger<CINotificationsController> logger)
        {
            _Adapter = adapter;
            _Bot = bot;
            _ConversationReferences = conversationReferences;
            _Logger = logger;
            _AppId = config.GetSection("MicrosoftAppId").Value;

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync(CINotification notificationData)
        {
            _Logger.LogInformation($"Got CI notification, {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(notificationData)}");
            var jobName = notificationData.JobName;
            var culpritsEmails = notificationData.Commiter;

            foreach (var conv in _ConversationReferences.Values)
            {
                await ((BotAdapter)_Adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_AppId, conv, GetBotCallBack(notificationData, conv), default);
            }

            return Ok(culpritsEmails);

        }

        private BotCallbackHandler GetBotCallBack(CINotification notificationData, ConversationReference conv)
        {
            return async (ctx, cts) =>
            {
                _Logger.LogDebug($"conversationId:[{conv.ActivityId}], serviceUrl:[{conv.ServiceUrl}]");
                var mention = new Mention();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(notificationData.Commiter))
                {
                    var membersByEmail = (await TeamsInfo.GetMembersAsync(ctx, cts)).ToDictionary(k => k.Email, v => v, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                    _Logger.LogDebug($"members:[{string.Join(",", membersByEmail.Keys)}]");
                    if (membersByEmail.TryGetValue(notificationData.Commiter, out var teamMemeber))
                    {
                        mention.Mentioned = teamMemeber;
                        mention.Text = $"<at>{teamMemeber.Name}</at>";
                    }

                    _Logger.LogDebug($"got mentions: {mention.Text}");

                }

                var msgText = $"{mention.Text} {notificationData.Message}";
                _Logger.LogDebug($"Sending message text: {msgText}");
                var replyActivity = MessageFactory.Text(msgText);
                replyActivity.Entities.Add(mention);

                await ctx.SendActivityAsync(replyActivity);
            };
        }
```

Of course an in memory dictionary  `_ConversationReferences` is a bad idea and I am looking for some way (API, something form the SDK ) to be able to list all groups the bot was added to or all conversation that were started ..

Do I have to store it in some DB or do i have a different option ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think such an API call exists. You can get from the Graph API, for instance, a [list of all apps installed into a team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamsappinstallation-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), but there's no such thing for group chats or 1-1 chats.

However, you -have- all that information already - simply store it your side, with so many good storage options these days (cloud and otherwise). In that case, it's fully under your control anyway.

Comment: thanks i figured as much.. just hoped there will be some option to get all conversation my bot was already added to .. :\

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this code

```
    // Create or get existing chat conversation with user
    var response = client.Conversations.CreateOrGetDirectConversation(activity.Recipient, activity.From, activity.GetTenantId());

    // Construct the message to post to conversation
    Activity newActivity = new Activity()
    {
        Text = "Hello",
        Type = ActivityTypes.Message,
        Conversation = new ConversationAccount
        {
            Id = response.Id
        },
    };

// Post the message to chat conversation with user
await client.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(newActivity, response.Id);
```

Got it here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet